# Recycler view wrap_content with drag and drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a to-do list just like "google keep" android app.
Basically, I need a scrolled layout with 2 lists: one of the checked items, and one of the unchecked ones.
The unchecked list should have an option to drag & drop the items in order to change their position.
My only problem is that I can't use width=wrap_content in recyclerview, and the layoutManager implementation that I found make the app crash when I try to drag & drop.

For the drag & drop I use [this library.](https://github.com/vinc3m1/DragSortAdapter)

My layout:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="views.fragments.ItemsFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_items_atv_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_items_btn_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_items_lv_unchecked_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_items_lv_checked_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_items_tv_empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Empty list"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The layout manager I use

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context)    {
    super(context, VERTICAL, false);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ItemTouchHelper in supportv7, and implement simplecallback,like this:

```
        mSimpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT|ItemTouchHelper.UP|ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();//得到拖动ViewHolder的position
            int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();//得到目标ViewHolder的position
            List<NHUser.DescriptionEntity> datas = mItemAdapter.getData();
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                //分别把中间所有的item的位置重新交换
                for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(datas, i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(datas, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
            mItemAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        }

    };
```